# Columns are missing after post back Infragistics Ultra Web Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

I have a simple web page that will display a data in an ultrawebgrid. The page runs fine at the start until I change the value of the Drop Down List. After selecting a new value on the Drop Down List, the other columns does not show. Below is my code on ultrawebgrid ASP.Net:

```
<igtbl:UltraGridBand AllowColSizing="Free">
                    <Columns>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="CONTAINERID" IsBound="True" Key="CONTAINERID"
                            Hidden="true">
                            <Header Caption="CONTAINERID">
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="1" />
                            </Header>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="1" />
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="WIPLOTHISTORYID" IsBound="True" Key="WIPLOTHISTORYID"
                            Hidden="true">
                            <Header Caption="WIPLOTHISTORYID">
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="1" />
                            </Header>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="1" />
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID" IsBound="True" Key="WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID"
                            Hidden="true">
                            <Header Caption="WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID">
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="2" />
                            </Header>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="2" />
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="SPECID" IsBound="True" Key="SPECID" Hidden="true">
                            <Header Caption="SPECID">
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="3" />
                            </Header>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="3" />
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="insertionnumber" Key="insertionnumber"
                            Width="65px">
                            <Header Caption="Insertion #">
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="4" />
                            </Header>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="4" />
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="insertionreasonname" Key="insertionreasonname"
                            Width="150px">
                            <Header Caption="Insertion Reason">
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="5" />
                            </Header>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="5" />
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="Operation" IsBound="True" Key="Operation"
                            Width="200px" Hidden="True">
                            <Header>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="6" />
                            </Header>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="6" />
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="Transaction Information" IsBound="True" Key="Transaction Information"
                            Width="200px">
                            <Header Caption="Transaction Information">
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="7" />
                            </Header>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="7" />
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:TemplatedColumn Width="280px">
                            <Header Caption="Details">
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="8"></RowLayoutColumnInfo>
                            </Header>
                            <CellTemplate>
                                <table style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="middle" style="width: 75%">
                                            <div>
                                                <%# Eval("Details").ToString().Replace("break", "<br/>") %></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="middle" style="width: 25%">
                                            <div style="text-decoration: Underline">
                                                <%# Eval("Values").ToString().Replace("break", "<br/>")%></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </CellTemplate>
                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="8"></RowLayoutColumnInfo>
                            </Footer>
                        </igtbl:TemplatedColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="Status" Key="Status" Hidden="true">
                            <Header Caption="Lot Status">

                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="9" />

                            </Header>



                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="9" />
                            </Footer>



                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="Date" DataType="System.DateTime" IsBound="True"
                            Width="150px" Key="Date">
                            <Header Caption="Date">

                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="10" />

                            </Header>

                            <Footer>
                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="7" />
                            </Footer>


                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <AddNewRow Visible="NotSet" View="NotSet">
                    </AddNewRow>
                </igtbl:UltraGridBand>
```

And my code behind on C# is:

```
ddlInsertion.Items.Clear();
            sqldsInsertionCount.SelectCommand = "SELECT containerid , w.insertionnumber FROM (SELECT wipdata.containerid, wipdata.insertionnumber FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.containerid , wl.insertionnumber FROM container c JOIN a_wiplot wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid JOIN a_wiplotdetails wld ON wld.wiplotid = wl.wiplotid JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata wldd ON wldd.wiplotdetailsid = wld.wiplotdetailsid WHERE c.containername = '" + txtLot.Text + "' AND wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid = '" + wipkey.ToString() + "' AND wldd.iswaferdata = 0 AND wldd.wipdatanamename != 'WAFER SCRIBE ID')wipdata GROUP BY wipdata.containerid , wipdata.insertionnumber UNION ALL SELECT wipdata.containerid , wipdata.insertionnumber FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.containerid , wl.insertionnumber FROM CONTAINER c JOIN a_wiplothistory wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid JOIN a_wiplotdetailshistory wld ON wld.wiplothistoryid = wl.wiplothistoryid JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory wldd ON wldd.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid WHERE c.containername = '" + txtLot.Text + "' AND wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid = '" + wipkey.ToString() + "' AND wldd.iswaferdata = 0 AND wldd.wipdatanamename != 'WAFER SCRIBE ID' )wipdata GROUP BY wipdata.containerid , wipdata.insertionnumber)w GROUP BY w.containerid , w.insertionnumber ORDER BY w.insertionnumber DESC";
            ddlInsertion.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("%", "%"));

            uwgDataCollection.Clear();            

            uwgDataCollection.DataSourceID = whdsDataCollection.ID;
            uwgDataCollection.DataBind();
            uwgDataCollection.ExpandAll();
            CustomizeColumns(txtSpec.Text.Substring(0, 4));
            ExpirePageCache();
```

Thanks again guys for helping :)

Comment: The BaseColumnName and Key of the column should match what is returned from the database including the case.  Does it?  What is DisplayLayout.AutoGenerateColumns set to and if set to True does the data show?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the .Clear() statement removes all the band on the grid. Once I tried removing it, everything runs smoothly. Thanks to alhalama for commenting on this. I owe you beer man :)